# T-SQL Check Why Record Is Missing

Tags: t-sql

If you've got a very complicated SELECT statement and some records aren't included because of a join, what is the easiest way to debug this and find the reasons why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could include your `ON` logic in the `WHERE` clause, phrase it like this:

```
WHERE 1=1
AND...
AND...
```

and just comment out as many of the terms until you isolate the unexpected behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

Change the JOINS / INNER JOINS to OUTER JOINS and look for NULLs where they shouldn't be.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help you, but when I find myself with a complex Select that I'm having a hard time maintaining, or debugging, I'll break it up into separate common table expressions (CTE's). I've found this makes many of my queries much easier to understand and maintain.

Answer (score 0):

[Binary Search stylee:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm)

If you have 10 joins, comment out the last 5.

Still have the problem? comment out the last 2/3 joins that are still uncommented

Still have the problem? comment out the last 1/2 joins that are still uncommented

Do this until you get down to it working, then the problem will lie in the last joins you commented out.

Yes you could do them one at a time but this is usually quicker.

Obviously you will have to comment out all the columns not used in the select statement, but I normally just put /* */ around all the columns, then put a * instead.

Just look at the number of results returned.